# What happens if TF(trap flag) is set to 0 in 8086 microprocessors?

Tags: debugging, assembly, flags, emu8086

Here I searched that:

> Trap Flag (T) – This flag is used for on-chip debugging. Setting trap
>   flag puts the microprocessor into single step mode for debugging. In
>   single stepping, the microprocessor executes a instruction and enters
>   into single step ISR.
>   If trap flag is set (1), the CPU automatically generates an internal
>   interrupt after each instruction, allowing a program to be inspected
>   as it executes instruction by instruction.
>   If trap flag is reset (0), no function is performed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_flag

Now I am coding on emu-8086. As explained, TF must be set in order to debugger work.

- Should I set a TF always myself or it is set automatically?
- If I somehow set a TF to 0, will the whole computer systems debuggers work or just emu-8086 wont debug?

Answer (score 5):

I've never used emu8086 but by looking at some screenshot of it and judging by its name it's probably an [emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator#Types) - this means it is not running the code natively.
Each instruction is changing the state of a virtual 8086 CPU (represented as a data structure in memory) and not the state of your real CPU.
With this emulation, emu8086 doesn't need to rely on the `TF` flag to single-step your program, it just needs to stop after one step of emulation and wait for you to hit another button.
This is also why you can find a thing such as "Step back".

---

If you were wondering what would happen if a debugged program (and not an emulated one) sets the `TF` flag then the answer is that it depends on the debugger.
The correct behaviour is the one where the debuggee receives the exceptions but this is hard to handle correctly (since the debugger itself uses the `TF` flag).
Some debugger just don't care and swallow the exception (i.e. they don't forward it to the program under debug) assuming that a well written program doesn't need to use the `TF` flag.
Unfortunately malwares routinely use a set of anti-debug technique including setting the `TF` and checking it back/waiting for exceptions to detect the presence of a debugger.

A truly transparent debugger has to handle the `RFLAGS` register  carefully.
When debugging with breakpoints the TF is not set while the program is executing, so there is nothing to worry about.
However when single stepping the TF is set during the next instruction, this is problematic during a `pushfd/q` and the debugger must explicitly handle that case to avoid detection.
If the debuggee sets the TF the debugger must pass the debug exception to the program - under current OS the TF won't last more than an instruction because the OS will catch the exception,
trasnform it in a signal and dispatch it to the program while clearing the TF. So the debugger can simply do a check before stepping into a `popfd/q` instruction.
Where the TF doesn't get cleared by the OS the debugger must effectively emulate `RFLAGS` with a copy.

Answer (score 1):

The debugger sets TF according to what it needs to do. The code being debugged should not modify TF.